# How to export Html.Kendo().Grid data to excel in generic way using javascript ?

Tags: javascript, excel, gridview, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

Please find the kendo grid code sample code in the view.

I am binding the data to the grid from the model , I need to export the grid data to the excel file on click of a button ... please suggest..

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>().Name("grid")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {

                            columns.Bound(p => p.field1).Width(20);
                            columns.Bound(p => p.field2).Width(50);
                            columns.Command(commands =>
                            {
                                commands.Edit(); 
                            }).Width(20);
                        }).Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InLine))
                                                    .Pageable(pageable =>                 pageable.ButtonCount(5)).Sortable()
                                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                                                            .Read(read => read.Action("LoadData", "Mycontroller")).PageSize(10)
                                                    .Model(model => model.Id(d => d.Id))
                                                    .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateData", "Mycontroller").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))))
```

Comment: please check these out https://github.com/uber-rob/kendo-grid-csv-download, http://jsfiddle.net/rhagerma/bCRm3/, http://www.somedave.com/posts/how-i-export-kendo-grids-to-excel-or-csv, http://blog.falafel.com/super-simple-spreadsheet-export-from-kendo-ui-grid/

Answer (score 2):

First you need to include the excel toolbar by adding the following line:
`.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())`
After that you can add the following :
`.Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx")
        .Filterable(true)
    )`